# Java: Multiple constructors forcing code reuse?

Tags: java, multiple-constructors

I have a class where one of its members is `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> elements`, and so I have a constructor that takes in that same type and all is good.

```
public elementArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> elements)
{
    this.elements =  elements;
    // a bunch of other stuff happens
}
```

However, I also need to be able to construct with an input of type `Double[][]`, so I first convert it to the 2D list type, and then call the original constructor...

```
public elementArray(Double[][] array)
{
    // convert Double[][] array to ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> elements
    this(elements);
}
```

Only, I can't call another constructor except as the first thing that happens in my constructor! Am I doomed to copy-paste here, or is there a clever way to do what I want?

Comment: Why not just add a private method `setElements(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> elements)` and call it from both constructors?

Comment: Have a private static method that does the conversion, and then you can just `this(convertArrayToList(elements));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to extract the conversion into a static method:

```
public elementArray(Double[][] array) {
    this(convert(elements));
}

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> convert(Double[][] array) {
    // convert Double[][] array to ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> elements
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have code before the call to `this()`, you also can't call other instance methods.

You can extract that conversion into a separate static method:

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> arrayToList(Double[][] d) {
    //convert and return list
}
```

And reuse this method in your second constructor:

```
public elementArray(Double[][] array) {
    this(arrayToList(array));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A common pattern to use would be to use a Builder instead.

https://iluwatar.github.io/java-design-patterns/patterns/builder/

Or a static factory method.

https://iluwatar.github.io/java-design-patterns/patterns/factory-method/

e.g. Using a static factory method, you would have only a single (possibly private) constructor, that accepts the rawest version of what your class needs.

```
public class elementArray{
    public elementArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> elements)
    {
        this.elements =  elements;
        // a bunch of other stuff happens
    }
    public static elementArray create(Double[][] array)
    {
        // convert Double[][] array to ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> elements
        return new elementArray(elements);
    }
    public static elementArray create(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> elements)
    {
        return new elementArray(elements);
    }
}
```

and then, instead of invoking the constructor, you would call the static methods.

```
elementArray.create(new double[][]{{1.0d},{2.0d}});
```

This has been used fairly commonly in recent Java, in Guava and the Java standard library.

see `Arrays.asList` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-

Answer (score -1):

But it is better to use the List instead of ArrayList.

```
    public elementArray(Double[][] array) {
        this(convert(elements));
    }

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> convert(Double[][] elements) {
        return IntStream.range(0, elements.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, elements[i].length)
                        .mapToObj(j -> elements[i][j])
                        .collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, (u, v) -> u.addAll(v)))
                .collect(ArrayList::new,
                        (u, v) -> v.add(u),
                        (u, v) -> u.addAll(v));
    }
```

Comment: This is far far far too complex.

Comment: Really? If the author uses List, it will be simple.

Comment: What about that: `Arrays.stream(array).map(d -> Arrays.stream(d).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: I already have a simple method for converting `Double[][]` to `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`. Other than that, this answer says the same as the other ones.